# HowTo migrate Qt project from plain-text ID translation format to a text-ID-based format

Tags: c++, qt, transactions, qt5

I have a quite big Qt project (with cmake\cpp\UI forms) and right now there is about 3000 text messages which I'd like to be translated.

All these messages (QString mostly) used `tr` to be properly translated. So the main thing is that I have plain-text ID and would like to switch to a [text-ID-based system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linguist-id-based-i18n.html#internationalizing-with-text-ids).

Switching to a [text-ID-based](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/i18n-source-translation.html#adding-meta-data-to-strings) for a big project quite a huge amount of works: all messages in source files must be additionally increased with special comments, like

```
\\= message_ID_1234
QString title = tr("My title");
```

So, I just wanted to ask where somebody could be struggling with migration from plain-text IDs to a text-ID-based system?
Maybe already exists scripts which could automate migration?

Comment: This sounds like a trivial job for a sed or perl script, no?

Comment: @Botje Maybe yes, maybe no, we have to add automatically generated ID names for all source messages and all UI forms (XML structure), so only after such additional changes original IDs could be used all over translations. 

So yes, the best solution for me will be to find such script which will modify all codebase.

Comment: So... see my answer? It's basic but it gets the job done if you feed it your entire codebase.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trivial perl script that inserts the comment into its arguments. Make sure to have a backup in place!

```
perl -pi -le 'printf "%s//= %s%04d\n", $1, $ENV{PREFIX}, $ENV{START_ID}++ if /^(\s*)(?:.*tr\()/' input.cpp
```

You can configure the starting ID and message prefix by the environment variables `START_ID` and `PREFIX`